# Adding BreezeJS functionality to Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, breeze

I am using angular-cli to generate an Angular 4 project.  I've used BreezeJS for a lot of my angular 1.x projects and wanted to use it in this one as well.

I haven't seen any official documentation from breeze on support for Angular 4 (or 2.x for that matter) and I've seen various other questions that have asked to incorporate it that were a bit dated.

Any chance that someone has pieced this together?  I would love to be able to use some of my common services that leverage BreezeJS from Angular 1.x in my Angular 4 project, it would save me a ton of time.

Comment: checked https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-bridge-angular2 ??

Comment: I saw that, but saw no updates since December so wasn't sure if it's actually supported in any way going forward.

Comment: seeing the downloads i would say it's worth a try

Answer (score 3):

@BrianNoyes has just created a 4 hour course on this very subject on Pluralsight.  Cannot recommend it highly enough.

He also explains how to use the tools created by Ideablade and used in their temphire demo app to create TS models on the client side which you will definitely want to use in addition to your server side model.

I've been developing Angular.js with Breeze for years and this was the thing that finally let me use Breeze comfortably with Angular 4.

Answer (score 1):

I just created an example project for Angular CLI & BreezeJS.

https://github.com/forCrowd/Labs-AngularCLI-BreezeJS

As you will see, to be able to make it run them together, I had to introduce a fix for OData adapter, but for the rest, it just works.

If you try it, let me know if you have any issues.

You can also check Breeze's itself `temphire` example project, can be very useful:

https://github.com/Breeze/temphire.angular

Comment: This is nice!  I was honestly hoping for an official Breeze release though because I want to be using something that is supported into the future.  I've gotten it to work using the library mentioned above, I just don't like that I'm doing it this way.

Comment: Sure, this should be a temporary solution. There is a related issue on breeze's github page, and I already reported this to them. I'm sure they will come up with a proper solution. Here is the link to that issue: https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/185